# getting selected radio button value in a popup

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a submit button named "details:, and a table which had radio buttons in each rows.
On selecting radio button and then clicking on my details button I want a popup to appear.

I have used something like this: I am not sure if the code I tried is really pathetic, but plz help me.
The form I used is GET.
This is my radio button:

```
<input type="radio" name="ID" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="radioValue" />
```

This is my submit button:

```
    <input type="submit" name="details1" value="Details" id="btndetails" class="btn"  />
    <div id="notice">
        <div class="pop">
        <?php 
        if(isset($_GET['details1']))
        {
           if(isset($_GET['ID']))
           {
              $n=$_GET['ID'];   
              echo$n;
              //do some sql queries with the id
           }
           else echo"Fail";
        }
?>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I have used jquery to ensure the clicks:

```
(function($) 
        {
            $(function() 
            {
             $('#btndetails').bind('click', function(e)
                {


                    // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
                     if($('.radioValue').is(':checked')) 
                    {  
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $("#notice").css("display", "block");                   
                    }
                        else
                        {
                         <?php echo"Please select the radio button";?>');
                        }

                });

            });

        })(jQuery);
```

the div notice is display:none;
Currently on clicking the radio button + details button i am getting a popup with msg "fail". How can  I get my radio button value in the pop up? Is my method wrong? I need to get the radio value in php so that i can use it to retrieve my DB.
I dont want to use any plugins for popups. I want it only by using php,html, css .
 Please help me.

Comment: please don't put error code here, please check basic things first.

Comment: @AyyanarG I have checked all basic things, Just the thing is i am not getting the radio button value ..

Answer (score 0):

**This might be your problem:**

```
 <input type="submit" name="details1" value="Details" id="btndetails" class="btn"  />
    <div id="notice">
        <div class="pop">
        <?php 
        if(isset($_GET['details1']))
        {
           if(isset($_GET['ID']))
           {
              $n=$_GET['ID'];   
              echo$n;
              //do some sql queries with the id
           }
           else echo"Fail";
        }
    ?>  // the first problem I found is here
        </div>

  </div>
```

also check your URL are you getting `id` parameter in `query string`

Comment: sorry for the small mistakes.. missing ?> was a copy paste mistake from my real code to this site. The main problem is retrieving the radio button value. :(

Comment: check your URL are you getting "id" parameter in query string ?

Comment: if there is no "Id" parameter code will run in else condition and your code will print "Fail"

Comment: also try by warping your else condition (  else echo"Fail"; ) in curly braces.  No need to do that but you can try using this if rest of your code is ok.

Comment: It doesnt enter  if(isset($_GET['ID'])) hence it gives the else part (which is echo"Fail")

Comment: I tried giving the braces for echo"fail"; but still its of no help :(

Comment: are you getting the "id" parameter in query string ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73403/discussion-between-ishan-demon-and-lilly-shk).